# I created UITabBar (not UITabBarController). How can I call tabBar: didSelectItem?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I created UITabBar (not UITabBarController). How can I call tabBar: didSelectItem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever view your `UITabBar` is displayed in much conform to the UITabBar Delegate Protocol.

When you initialize your UITabBar, assign it's delegate to the view it's contained within.  Then within your views `@interface` block add `<UITabBarDelegate>` after your superclass declaration.  This informs your view that it contains a `UITabBar` and whenever you select a portion of `UITabBar`, I want this view to be send the message `tabBar: didSelectItem.`  From there on out it's up to you to implement how the view reacts to selecting certain items.

For more information check out the [UITabBarDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

**Updated for comment**

If you want to call it programatically you need to get a reference to the item you would have selected if you were calling this by a touch.  All tab bar items are stored in an array so you can just reference it like so.

```
UITabBarItem *tabItem = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:(index of object)];
```

then just call the delegate method

```
[self tabBar:self.tabBar didSelectItem:tabItem];
```

Comment: i want to call this delegate in code (not using touch on screen)